# initialize multiple variables with constructor overloading

Tags: c++, constructor

Let's say in a class a constructor is overloaded. Can multiple data members be initialized for the single object using different constructors of the same class?

eg :

```
class demo{

    int size;
    double k;
    public:
    demo(int s){
        size=s;
    }
    demo(double p){
      k = size+p;
    }
    void show(){
      cout<<size<<" "<<k<<"\n";
    }
};

int main(){

    demo a = demo(0);
    a = 4.7;
    a.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What are you asking? If you construct with a double, `k` is undefined because `size` is undefined and `k` is an undefined value plus `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, once the object is constructed, it's constructed.

Let's go through your code and see what it does (assuming no optimizations, please note that many modern compilers will do some [copy-elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) even in debug or -O0 modes):

1. `demo(0);`

   The code `demo(0)` calls the `demo(int s)` constructor. A temporary [rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) is created. So now we have a temporary object with the values:

   ```
   size = 0
   k = uninitialized
   ```
2. `demo a = demo(0);`

   `demo a` is then created using an implicit [copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

   We now have a `demo` object named `a` with the following values:

   ```
   size = 0
   k = uninitialized
   ```
3. `a = 4.7;`

   Because `a` is already constructed, this will call an implicit [assignment-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/3033711). The default assignment-operator will copy all the values from one object into the other object. This means the `4.7` needs to be converted into a `demo` object first. This is possible because of your `demo(double p)` constructor.

   So a temporary `demo` object will be created with the values:

   ```
   size = uninitialized
   k = uninitialized + 4.7 = undefined
   ```

   These values will be copied into `a` and so both of `a`'s data members will be undefined.

**Possible Solutions**

[songyuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24308443/3033711)'s solution of using a constructor with multiple parameters is one good way of doing it.

Using setters is another way.

Either way, I would recommend having your constructors provide default values for your data-members.

```
demo(int s)
{
    size = s;
    k = 0.0; // or some other suitable value
}
```

Here's how you could create a setter.

```
void setK (double p)
{
    k = size + p;
}
```

You could then do this:

```
int main ()
{
    demo a (0) ;

    a.setK (4.7) ;
    a.show () ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define a ctor which can take multiple parameters to initialize multiple data members:

```
demo(int s, double p) {
    size = s;
    k = size + p;
}
```

and then

```
int main() {
    demo a(0, 4.7);
    a.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're after the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns/Creational_Patterns).